# Why does driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2ycp _5xhk']") function fetch data in different formats?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am developing a scraper for someone living in USA from Pakistan, it captures facebook event data (title, time, data, days and details) using selenium chromedriver. I used  driver.find_element_by_xpath() to get the data. But the data it fetches is in a different format when tried it in USA.

I used  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2ycp _5xhk']") method to fetch the date and time of the event and then storing it in a string python. Then i used split() method to split the strings so i can parse date, month, year and time. I tried debugging and found that it gets data in different formats for both counties Pakistan and USA. Why am i having this problem?

```py
driver.get("Some URL i used")
date_time = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2ycp _5xhk']").text

event_date_time = date_time.split()
```

The output picture links are attached:

In Pakistan:

[image]

In USA:

[image]

Comment: Seems like an issue with the way Facebook is displaying their data in various languages, and doesn't have much of anything to do with Selenium.

Comment: is it the date of server. Facebook do not use only one server in the world.

Comment: @Christine you are absolutely right. I just tried it with a VPN and changed my IP to USA IP and it showed me different format as well.

Comment: @sgrillon Yes you are right as well! Its the facebook server which displays different format in different countires.

Comment: There's not much we can do here from a selenium perspective, but you could write a date-handler method which takes a date, determines its format, and returns a "normalized" date that is consistent across all languages.

Comment: @Christine Yes i have already done that. Thanks for the help!